# CATransaction synchronize exception while scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

While I'm scrolling in `UITableView` few seconds after I'm having an exception as follow:

```
 +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception
```

When user scrolling the table and then stop scolling, I'm processing an `UIImage` and show it back in the table:

```
- (UIImage *)applyRoundCornersToImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    if (self.isCancelled)
        return nil;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageView.bounds cornerRadius:23.0] addClip];

    [image drawInRect:imageView.bounds];
    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageView.image;
}
```

On my `UIViewController` that holds the table I've an animation on *main thread* which run constantly:

```
- (void)startSpinner
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CABasicAnimation *rotation;
        rotation =[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
        rotation.fromValue =@0.0f;
        rotation.toValue =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2*M_PI)];
        rotation.duration =3;// Speed
        rotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;// Repeat forever. Can be a finite number.
        [self.imageSpinnerSonar.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];
    });
}
```

Maybe it's relevant, It happens no matter I'm start/stop the animation.